# Bash scripting to process an experiment data file

Tags: shell-script

I have a .txt file with a sample snapshot of the content shown below. I have to sum all the field values and output them. That is, sum total  CEPSDIST (MEAN), sum total SRMR, etc. I want to use bash scripting for this. Any sample scripts to do this?

*N.B.: I have never done scripting but using it will make my experimentation and data analysis quick. I am looking forward to learn it but not from scratch, and rather from a sample example from where I can learn backwards.*

```
Individual results
[0001 of 0002]
TARGET   : cheb_M_10_mic_F01_sa1.wav
REFERENCE: orig_mic_F01_sa1.wav
    TIMEDIFF       :      0 samples (0.000 s)
    CEPSDIST (MEAN):   6.96 dB
    CEPSDIST (MED) :   6.74 dB
    SRMR           :   1.06
    LLR      (MEAN):   1.75
    LLR      (MED) :   2.00
    FWSEGSNR (MEAN):  -4.17 dB
    FWSEGSNR (MED) :  -6.12 dB
    PESQ           :   0.07

[0002 of 0002]
TARGET   : cheb_M_20_mic_F01_sa1.wav
REFERENCE: orig_mic_F01_sa1.wav
    TIMEDIFF       :      0 samples (0.000 s)
    CEPSDIST (MEAN):   6.75 dB
    CEPSDIST (MED) :   6.50 dB
    SRMR           :   1.32
    LLR      (MEAN):   1.70
    LLR      (MED) :   2.00
    FWSEGSNR (MEAN):  -3.84 dB
    FWSEGSNR (MED) :  -5.82 dB
    PESQ           :   0.05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `awk`:

Here the file extract.awk

```
BEGIN 
{
    SRMR = 0;
}
{
    if($1 == "SRMR") {SRMR += $3}  
}
END 
{
    print "SRMR sum is: " SRMR;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
awk -f extract.awk < your_data_file
```

EDIT:

All your fields won't be extracted the same way. To understand how a file is parsed with awk, you can use this basic debug file:

```
# debug.awk
{
    print "For line '" $0 "'"
    print "$1 is '" $1 "'"   
    print "$2 is '" $2 "'"   
    print "$3 is '" $3 "'"   
    print "$4 is '" $4 "'"   
    print "$5 is '" $5 "'"   
    print "$6 is '" $6 "'"
    print ""
}
```

Comment: I'd expand it with a switch/case statement - `switch ($1) { case "SRMR":  SRMR += $3; break` etc... but it only works in gawk, and usually only in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks @purplepsycho. Especially the debug.awk was really helpful to understand the workings.